# Dataiku error - DSS doesn't support dataframes containing multiple columns with the same name

Tags: dataiku

I'm can't able to figure out why I'm getting following error "DSS doesn't support dataframes containing multiple columns with the same name."

But, in my dataframe I don't have any  multiple columns having same name.  Although, I've same data set having in two different columns with two different names.

```
Example:

Col1 | Col2
-------------------
111 | 111
--------------------
222 | 222
--------------------
333 | 333
--------------------
444 | 444
--------------------
555 | 555
--------------------
```

Screenshot attached -

[image]

---

UPDATE: Sorry, I've fixed it. The data set had some duplicate columns. Actually the dataset is so high I couldn't able to identify whether there is duplicate columns or not. Also, new to Pandas & till now trying to fig out how to do stuff quickly using it.

One more thing was before sending the data to dataiku dataset I was creating a CSV of that data frame & that was working properly. So, I thought maybe issue is somewhere else.

Comment: It's difficult to answer your question without more info/material/logs.

Comment: @6761646f6e fixed it. Issue was in myside. Thanks for the reply.